# How to map API with multiple objects [Spree API V2 & ReactJS]

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, spree

I'm building a webshop, using ReactJS for the front-end and Spree (Ruby) for the back-end.

Spree offers an [API](https://guides.spreecommerce.org/api/v2/storefront/#operation/Show%20Product) solution to connect the front-end and the back-end with one and other.

I'm trying to display products with product images, but Spree's API is setup in a specific way that product images and products aren't in the same object.

The API response is:

```
 {
    (holds products)data: [],
    (Holds product images)included:[],
 }
```

My goal is to create an `ul` with the product information and product image displayed.

I've tried to map [my API link](https://stern-telecom-react-salman15.c9users.io/api/v2/storefront/products?include=images) which

```
           this.state.arrays.map((product) => 
              product.data
            )
```

Which responds with the data object, but I cant for example do `product.data.name` because it returns an `undefined` response

**DATA RESPONSE IN THE LOG**

```
ProductsList.js:28 PL 
[undefined]
Index.js:42 productsData 
{}
ProductsList.js:28 PL 
[Array(5)]
0: Array(5)
0: {id: "5", type: "image", attributes: {…}}
1: {id: "4", type: "image", attributes: {…}}
2: {id: "1", type: "image", attributes: {…}}
3: {id: "3", type: "image", attributes: {…}}
4: {id: "2", type: "image", attributes: {…}}
length: 5
__proto__: Array(0)
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
```

**Product Index page**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import ProductsList from "./products/ProductsList";
import axios from 'axios';



const REACT_VERSION = React.version;
const include = '?include=images';
const API = 'https://stern-telecom-react-salman15.c9users.io/api/v2/storefront/products' + include;

const styles = {
  card: {
    maxWidth: 345,
  },
  media: {
    height: 140,
  },
};

class Index extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            products: [],
            productsData: {},
            isLoading: false,
            error: null,
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ isLoading: true });
    axios.get(API)
      .then(result => this.setState({
        products: result.data.data,
        productsData: result.data,
        isLoading: false,
      }))
      .catch(error => this.setState({
        error,
        isLoading: false
      }));
      // console.log(
      //   'productsData', 
      //   this.state.productsData

      //   )
  }
  render() {
    const { products, productsData,isLoading, error } = this.state;

    if (error) {
      return <p>{error.message}</p>;
    }
     if (isLoading) {
      return <p>Loading ...</p>;
    }
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
          <h1>React version: {REACT_VERSION}</h1>
          <ProductsList products={this.state.productsData}/>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

ProductsList.propTypes = {
  greeting: PropTypes.string
};

export default Index
```

**ProductList Page**

```
import React from "react"
import PropTypes from "prop-types"

import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Card from '@material-ui/core/Card';
import CardActionArea from '@material-ui/core/CardActionArea';
import CardActions from '@material-ui/core/CardActions';
import CardContent from '@material-ui/core/CardContent';
import CardMedia from '@material-ui/core/CardMedia';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';

const url = "https://stern-telecom-react-salman15.c9users.io"

class ProductsList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const { products } = this.props;
    const arrays = Object.values( {products} );
    this.state = {
      products,
      arrays
    };
  }
  render () {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <ul>
          <p>Shop Products</p>
          {
          // console.log(
          //   'PL',
            // this.state.arrays.map((product) => 
            //   product.data
            // )
          // )
          this.state.arrays.map(product =>
            <li key={product.objectID}>
            <Card>
                  <CardActionArea>
                    <CardMedia
                      image= {url + ''}
                      title={product.data.attributes.name}
                    />
                    <CardContent>
                      <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="h2">
                       {product.data.attributes.name}
                      </Typography>
                      <Typography component="p">
                        {product.data.attributes.description}
                      </Typography>
                    </CardContent>
                  </CardActionArea>
                  <CardActions>
                    <Button size="small" color="primary">
                     {product.data.attributes.display_price} 
                    </Button>
                    <Button size="small" color="primary">
                      add to cart
                    </Button>
                  </CardActions>
                </Card>
            </li>
            )
          }
        </ul>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

ProductsList.propTypes = {
  greeting: PropTypes.string
};
export default ProductsList
```

What I expect to get as Result is product information and image

Comment: what is `this.state.arrays`

Comment: Hi, @bUff23 I added it to my code. The AP Object get's passed on the the productList page and turned into a variable called arrays. Which I turn in a state component

Comment: Can you post a sample of the json data you receive from the APi? It is very hard to see what problem you are facing without having that info

Comment: @dubes I've added the data I receive

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The manipulation after you're fetching json data is wrong. The returned result is a json object with a `data` property which is the array you want to pass and get the products.

You either pass the `products` to `<ProductsList>` component:

```
const { products, images, isLoading, error } = this.state;
...
<ProductsList products={products} images={images}/>
```

and then use it directly:

```
class ProductsList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const { products, images } = this.props;
    this.state = {
      products,
      images
    };
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

or use `props.products.data` to directly get the products array inside `ProductsList` constructor:

```
class ProductsList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const products = this.props.products.data;
    const images = this.props.products.included;
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

there is no need of using `const arrays = Object.values({ products });` because you already have an array with the products:

```
...
products: result.data.data,   // products is an array with products
images: result.data.included, // images is an array with all posible images
productsData: result.data,    // productsData.data is an array with products
...
```

Also, the product object does not contain any attribute named `data`:

```
<Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="h2">
  {product.data.attributes.name}
</Typography>
<Typography component="p">
  {product.data.attributes.description}
</Typography>
```

you have to access its' properties directly like this:

```
<Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="h2">
  {product.attributes.name}
</Typography>
<Typography component="p">
  {product.attributes.description}
</Typography>
```

**EDIT**

Here is a [CodeSandbox project](https://codesandbox.io/embed/lyyv3zrxlm) with your code simpified and without calling the Axios request (because [it's restrticted](https://stern-telecom-react-salman15.c9users.io/api/v2/storefront/products?include=images)) and having the data in a JSON file instead. You should also initialize `isLoading` to true, or make the `Index` component to not render before it has some data:

```
class Index extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      ...
      isLoading: true,
    }
  }
}
```

Here is an *updated* screenshot with it working:

[image: CodeSandbox Screenshot]

And the simplified `<ProductsList/>` component:

```
import React from "react";

const url = "https://stern-telecom-react-salman15.c9users.io";

class ProductsList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    const { products, images } = this.props;
    //const arrays = Object.values( {products} );
    this.state = {
      products,
      images
      //arrays
    };
  }
  render() {
    const { products, images } = this.state;
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <p>Shop Products</p>
        {console.log("PL", products, images)
        // this.state.arrays.map(product =>
        //   <li key={product.objectID}>

        //   </li>
        //   )
        }
        <ul>
          {products.map(product => (
            <li key={product.key}>
              <h4>{product.attributes.name}</h4>
              <p>Description: {product.attributes.description}</p>
              <p>Price: {product.attributes.display_price} </p>
              <p>Images:</p>
              <div>
                {product.relationships.images.data.map(({ id }) => {
                  let image = images.find(image => image.id == id);
                  return image ? (
                    <img src={`${url}/${image.attributes.styles[1].url}`}/>
                  ) : null;
                })}
              </div>
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default ProductsList;
```

**EDIT 2**

To add images it's a very simple task. You just have to combine products array with images and display the images. Check the updated `<ProductsList/>` component. Of course you have to pass both `products` and `images` to `<ProductsList/>` (`const images = productsData.included;`). Check the updated [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/lyyv3zrxlm), `<ProductsList/>` component and screenshot.

**EDIT 3**

Regarding the images; each image has a `styles` property which is an array of different sizes:

```
"included": [
{
  "id": "5",
  "type": "image",
  "attributes": {
    "viewable_type": "Spree::Variant",
    "viewable_id": 4,
    "styles": [
      {
        "url": "...",
        "width": "48",
        "height": "48"
      },
      {
        "url": "...",
        "width": "100",
        "height": "100"
      },
      {
        "url": "...",
        "width": "240",
        "height": "240"
      },
      {
        "url": "...",
        "width": "600",
        "height": "600"
      }
    ]
  }
}
...
]
```

in order to map the images to each product, we have to map all the images stored in each product by using `product.relationships.images.data` which is an array of object with `id` and `type` properties. For each image in the product images, we search through the images array using `let image = images.find(image => image.id == id)` and if we find an image then we use one of the four available sizes or maybe all of the available sizes (`48px`, `100px`, `240px`, `600px`); I choose `image.attributes.styles[1].url`, so I display the second element of the available image sizes, which is the `100px` size image:

```
product.relationships.images.data.map(({ id }) => {
  let image = images.find(image => image.id == id);
  return image ? (
    <img src={`${url}/${image.attributes.styles[1].url}`}/>
  ) : null;
})
```

**EDIT 4**

If you need to get one image per product, then you can use a function that checks whether an image exists and then gets the image from the images array:

```
// Here we're using an inline function to get the product image
// You can also create a normal class function and use that instead

{product.relationships.images.data.length > 0 &&
  (() => {
    // { id } is the destructure of product.relationships.images.data[0]
    // which means it extract the property id to a stand alone variable
    const { id } = product.relationships.images.data[0];
    const image = images.find(image => image.id == id);
    return image ? (
      <img src={`${url}/${image.attributes.styles[1].url}`} />
    ) : null;
  })()
}
```

This is an inline function that isolates its' contents and executes immediately:

```
(() => { ... })()
```

You can read more about [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)
 (`{ id } = object`).

Comment: Thanks for your reply Christos,

I was testing `productsData` an an object `{ }` and `products` as an array `[ ]`

Passing on productsData as an object to the products list en changing it to an array seemed to make the data readable when logging `product.data` it does show a data feed of multiple array's. But when I try to map an array the response is undefined

Comment: @Salman if you read carefully my answer from the beggining to the end, you'll see that you don't do it right. You don't have to convert anything using `Object.values`; the JSON data already have an array with the products (`data.data`). The data you're getting to log in `ProductsList.js:28 PL [Array(5)]` **are actually the images** `included` member not the `data: [...]` which has the products.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, the only problem is that I don't only need the `data` array, but also the images from included. To create a product list including images. Right now the array list doesn't have images so I have to combine both data from `data` and `include`

Comment: @Salman it's really simple and a matter of filtering. Check my edits and code to see how you'll do it.

Comment: Hi Chris, your last edit worked perfectly, Thank you! Could you explain a bit more what you did regarding finding the image?

Comment: Also another question, It now returns all images, what If I only want to return a single image

Comment: @Salman check my edit to see the images explanation. What do you mean you want one image? If you want to display just one image (*just the fiorst for example*), then you don't use and enumarate all the items of `product.relationships.images.data` but just get the first one if it actually has `>= 1` images. Can edit and write an example if you like.

Comment: Chris, amazing. Wish I could give you 50 more points. What I meant to say is, what If I only want to show the first image of each product with size 600px would I then do `let image = images.find(image => image.id == id >= 1) ;` and show product `<img src={`${url}/${image.attributes.styles[3].url}`} /> `

Comment: @Salman thank you. You don't really have to do `image.id == id >= 1`; `image.id == id` just checks if there is the same id and it's a boolean comparison, just leave it as is `.find(image => image.id == id)`. That is exactly how you'd display the `600px` image, `image.attributes.styles[3].url` selects the fourth styles element (`styles[3]`) which is the `600x600` image.

Comment: Sure, check the updated code in [CodeSandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/embed/lyyv3zrxlm). The links of the API and the images do not work anymore because I assume you've changed something to the endpoint you have had, but it doesn'ty matter, you'll see how you can use only one image for each product.

Comment: Yes, I my workspace was being archived, so the development server was offline. However it indeed works. I see you're not mapping the array anymore, but you're actually `(()` have an empty function. Could you care to explain how that works? You're also using  `{ id }` to get it from the `product.relationships.images.data[0]` also new for me.

Comment: Check my new edit, you'll see the explanation of both destructuring assignment and inline function.

Comment: Thanks Chris, not only did this solve my problem, but I've also learned more about destructing of objects and filtering through multiple arrays